# Dart return Future.value is always null

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, dart-async

I am trying to build a URL from a Firebase Storage file but the `Future<String>` I have built always seems to return `null`. This is the `Future` I am calling:

```
Future<String> getUrlFromStorageRefFromDocumentRef(
      DocumentReference docRef) async {
    try {
      docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
          String filename = documentSnapshot.get('file');
          firebase_storage.Reference ref = firebase_storage
              .FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('/flamelink/media/$filename');
          if (ref == null) {
            return Future.error("Storage Reference is null");
          } else {
            print(ref.fullPath);
            return Future.value(
                'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/${ref.fullPath}');
          }
        } else {
          return Future.error('No Snapshot for DocumentReference ${docRef.id}');
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return Future.error('No DocumentReference for ID ${docRef.id}');
    }
  }
```

The line in question is :

```
return Future.value(
                'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/${ref.fullPath}');
```

It's worth noting that the `String` is generated from the `Firebase Storage` path and everything looks perfect until it comes to return the value.

It should return the `String` value back to my calling code which at the moment looks like this:

```
DocButtonCallback docCallback = () async {
      bool isKidsDoc = item.screenId == StringsManager.instance.screenIdKids;
      try {
        // first we need to get the URL for the document ...
        var url = await AssetManager.instance
            .getUrlFromStorageRefFromDocumentRef(isKidsDoc
                ? feature.relatedDocumentKidsRef
                : feature.relatedDocumentRef);

        String urlString = url.toString();

        canLaunch(urlString).then((value) {
          launch(urlString);
        }).catchError((error) {
          // TODO: open alert to tell user
        });
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
      }
    };
```

I have tried many different ways to get that `String` including:

```
DocButtonCallback docCallback = () async {
      bool isKidsDoc = item.screenId == StringsManager.instance.screenIdKids;
      await AssetManager.instance
          .getUrlFromStorageRefFromDocumentRef(isKidsDoc
              ? feature.relatedDocumentKidsRef
              : feature.relatedDocumentRef)
          .then((urlString) {
        canLaunch(urlString).then((value) {
          launch(urlString);
        }).catchError((error) {
          // TODO: open alert to tell user
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        // TODO: open alert to tell user
      });
    };
```

For some reason, the `Future` always returns `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the `Future` value inside the `then()` callback, which essentially returns this value from the callback itself rather than from your `getUrlFromStorageRefFromDocumentRef()` function. There you should only need to add a return statement before that:

Current:

```dart
docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    ...
```

After:

```dart
/// Adding the return statement here to return the actual value
/// returned internally by the then callback
return docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
    ...
```

If you hover over the `then()` callback, your IDE should show you that this callback will return `Future<T>` (or whatever generic type placeholder) which need to be returned as well in order to make it available